# linguex and booklet

Tags: linguex, booklet

I am encountering some issue with `linguex` while using the `booklet` package. Basically, when I want to list more than one sentence within the same number, I get a weird symbol - an underscore with a dot on top of it. The code and a picture to what I get follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage[print]{booklet}
\setpdftargetpages
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\firstrefdash}{}
\def\exr{\setcounter{ExNo}{0}\ex}

\usepackage{tipa} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false
      ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{booklet_biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\begin{center}
\textsc{Tile2}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2] 

\ex. \ag. Gianni arriv{\` o} due ore fa \\
John arrived two hours does \\
'John arrived two hours ago.'
\bg. Gianni arriva due ore prima  \\
John arrives two hours before. \\
'John arrives two hours ealier.'

\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

For the screenshot: [click](https://postimg.org/image/ljhyjlalj/)

I'm getting crazy in trying to figure out how to fix this. Any help or suggestion is very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: In order to add screen shots, don't use external sites; click on the small icon above the editing window (the one with the mountain) and you'll be guided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had tried to simplify the example, you would have noted that `booklet` is completely irrelevant to the matter. Actually, a minimal example that reproduces the issue is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\ex. \ag. Gianni arriv\`{o} due ore fa \\
John arrived two hours does \\
'John arrived two hours ago.'
\bg. Gianni arriva due ore prima  \\
John arrives two hours before. \\
'John arrives two hours earlier.'

\end{document}
```

Just reverse the calling order between `tipa` and `linguex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \ag. Gianni arriv\`{o} due ore fa \\
John arrived two hours does \\
'John arrived two hours ago.'
\bg. Gianni arriva due ore prima  \\
John arrives two hours before. \\
'John arrives two hours earlier.'

\end{document}
```

[image]

I fixed a couple of typos. I didn't fix the nonsensical translation of “fa” into “does”. You should.